# How to grant privileges to current user

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to make a java application that uses a database. I've downloaded db2 and created a user 'student'. I have the following lines in my program:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "student", "xxxxxx");
```

and

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sifra, naziv " +
                        " FROM predmet " +
                        " WHERE bodovi > 20" );
```

And the second one throws a SqlSyntaxErrorException with the following message: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501.

So I looked it up and it seems that the user doesn't have the required level of privilege. So when I tried to run the query in db2 command line, I got:

> The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation. Authorization ID: "STUDENT".  Operation: "SELECT".

So since obviously I barely know what I'm doing, I don't know how to grant 'student' the necessary privileges. That is, I don't know what user could give him the privileges since I never created another user. I've seen 'db2admin' mentioned (I'm using windows), but I don't know what to do with that piece of information. I don't know how to check the existing users or which password to use for db2admin (if that's even possible).

Comment: you don't have your schema and tables posted its bit tough ... but try to run following query it will grant access to user your are trying ----

db2 grant dataaccess on database to user YOURUSERNAME

Comment: @ASP Sorry, didn't really know which information was relevant. If I try to do that I get: _"STUDENT" does not have the privilege to perform operation "GRANT"._ And I don't know how to use another user.

Comment: you will need an account that has admin privileges in order to run that query look around

Comment: See if db2 created a new windows user (typically: `db2admin`) when you installed it, and try connecting/running the `grant` as that user (default pwd might be same as the user name, unless you provided one during install).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for this user to have access you need to determine at what level: Server, Instance, Database, Table, etc. Here is an article about [DB2 Granting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0005804.html) and various levels.

To make it easy, let assume this user will have full database privileges and we'll use [GRANT DATABASE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-130&lang=en)

```
GRANT ACCESSCTRL, BINDADD, CONNECT, CREATETAB, CREATE_EXTERNAL_ROUTINE, 
    CREATE_NOT_FENCED_ROUTINE, DATAACCESS, DATAACCESS, EXPLAIN, 
    IMPLICIT_SCHEMA, LOAD, QUIESCE_CONNECT, SECADM, SQLADM, WLMADM ON 
    DATABASE DB_STUDENT TO student;
```